# Undefined $DBI::errstr using DBI Perl and MySql on Windows-7-x64

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, windows-7-x64

Using:

MySQL 5.5
ActivePerl v5.14.1
Windows 7 64bit

The following script has an undefined $DBI::errstr on the failure of the execute call:

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe -w
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:cq','root','password') or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

# This SQL should fail because of a foreign key constraint
my $sql = "delete from Player where ID=6462"; 

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

The output when the script is run is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $DBI::errstr in concatenation (.) or string at testmysql2.pl line 10.
SQL Error:
```

The SQL run via HeidiSQL provides the expected Foreign Key error:
(I can't insert the image as I'm a new user)

The same script run on Windows XP 32-bit provides the expected error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cq`.`messageboard`, CONSTRAINT `messageboard_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PlayerID`) REFERENCES `player` (`ID`)) at testmysql2.pl line 10.
SQL Error2: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cq`.`messageboard`, CONSTRAINT `messageboard_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PlayerID`) REFERENCES `player` (`ID`))
```

Note:

The problem occurs regardless of the SQL, for example a SQL syntax error will also result in an undefined $DBI::errstr

Interestingly a connection error is returned - for example, stop the MySQL service - run the script and the following output is given, as expected:

```
DBI connect('cq','root',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) at testmysql2.pl line 4
Connection Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Setting a trace level provides no useful information (for me):

```
$sth->trace(5, "trace.txt");
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

with a snippet of trace.txt with some reformatting as:

```
dbd_st_free_result_sets
mysql_st_internal_execute MYSQL_VERSION_ID 50147
parse_params statement delete from Player where ID=6462
dbd_st_execute returning imp_sth->row_num 18446744073709551614
execute= ( undef ) [1 items] at testmysql2.pl line 11
DESTROY for DBD::mysql::st (DBI::st=HASH(0x29dc0a8)~INNER) thr#2a97e8
```

Correct SQL operates as expected. I'm guessing this is a bug for Windows 7 64bit? - but I'm unclear/lost as to how to resolve or find the correct place to report/find out definitively.

If you got this far ... thanks for reading!

Comment: What version of `DBI` and `DBD::mysql`?

Answer (score 1):

Add use warnings as PrintError is on by default and that causes DBI to issue a warn if something fails. Also, try changing the second $DBI::errstr to $sth->errstr. If that does not work then I am suspicious that execute is returning a fail return but DBD::mysql has not called set_err internally.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback bohica. Warnings were on via the -w flag, but I have added "use warnings" - same result. I had tried $sth->errstr - and yes the same result an undefined string. So it looks like a bug in the DBD::mysql for Windows-7-x64 ... any advice on where to from here?

Comment: Write a small self contained test case and report it on rt.cpan.org or mail it to the dbi-users at http://dbi.perl.org. I'm not saying it is a bug but I maintain DBD::ODBC where it works e.g., perl -le 'use DBI; $h=DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:x","x","x",{RaiseError=>0,PrintError=>0});$s=$h->prepare("select * from does_not_exist");$s->execute or die $s->errstr;'
Invalid object name 'does_not_exist'. (SQL-42S02) [state was 42S02 now 42000]
Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQL-42000) at -e line 1.

Comment: Thanks again bohica - I'll do that. As they say down under - onya mate.

Comment: Yes it is worth an upvote - but I don't have a reputation of >= 15 so I prevented from doing this... apologies.

Comment: I'd post that to the dbi-users list as well (you can find it at http://dbi.perl.org/support) as with 78 rts for DBD::mysql it looks as if there is a backlog and someone on the dbi-users list might be able to help. I'd look at it myself but I don't really use mysql anymore and I'm short on tuits.

Comment: Thanks bohica - I'll do that.

Comment: Hello - got an answer and a fix via bug-DBD-mysql@rt.cpan.org: 
Excellent - thanks Christian!

I moved to 4.020 for 64bit Windows on ActiveState 5.14 via:

ppm install http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x64/5.14/1401/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.ppd

 For anyone else stuck on a broken DBD-mysql, you can get ActiveState's
 properly working 4.018 for 5.12 via this command:

 ppm install http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.12/1205/C/CA/
CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.018.ppd

 For other versions you can try just changing the relevant parts in the
 URL.